# JavaFX Errors with FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));

Tags: javafx

I can not figure out for the life of me the problem with this code. I have done research on many similar questions here, addressing whether the directories were correct, possible wrong function calls etc.

I am hoping someone can help me out. Everything is in a file called login in an app called loginapp.

Here is Login.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package login;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Login extends Application   {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Fracken");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Here is Login.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="317.0" prefWidth="326.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="login.Login">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="45.0" promptText="Username" />
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="115.0" promptText="Password" />
      <Button fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="184.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="btnLoginAction" text="Login" />
      <Button fx:id="btnReset" layoutX="232.0" layoutY="184.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="btnResetAction" text="Reset" />
      <Label fx:id="lblMessage" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="236.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="187.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am sure the issue is with

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
```

I get this error.

```
Executing C:\Users\David\Desktop\Java Project\loginapp\dist\run122343396\loginapp.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at login.Login.start(Login.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Please help me, I have looked at other's similar issues on here but no solutions worked.

Comment: The error says "location is required", which simply means the path to your FXML file is wrong.

Comment: What would the path be, an absolute one including C:/ or a local such as /login/Login.fxml. I've tried multiple paths.

Comment: The path is a url that is relative to the location of the current class. What package is `Login.fxml` in? (The `FXMLLoader` is expecting it in the same package as the `Login` class, i.e. in `login`.) Is the FXML file deployed to the jar file?

Comment: It is C:\Users\David\Desktop\Java Project\loginapp\src\login\Login.fxml for the full path. I've tried what most videos have as /login/Login.fxml and even the absolute path.

Comment: Well the file path is hardly likely to make any sense after the application is deployed (you really think it's going to be able to find the `src` directory at runtime?). Is the FXML file deployed to the jar file?

Comment: No, I don't think it is. How would I change that in Netbeans

Comment: Well then I assume that is the problem. You need to configure your IDE so the fxml file is deployed to it.

Comment: I actually do see it now in the jar directory, and it matches up with login/Login.fxml

Comment: A duplicate of [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) mixed-in with a bit weirdness (two loaders, why?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getClass().getResource("Login.fxml")` should return a non-null value, since using `Class.getResource` looks up the resouce relative to the class. Since you seem to have placed the resource in the `login` package, using a class in that package with resource name `Login.fxml` should work.

For some reason you do not use the `FXMLLoader` that you pass this resource `URL` to. Instead you use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml")
```

I.e. you use the classloader to load the file. The classloader however does not know about the class you retrieve it from and therefore tries to locate `Login.fxml` in the default package.

If you use a classloader, you should use the full path, i.e.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("login/Login.fxml")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried everything and this worked. This is a nice explanation of why it worked. Clarifies it immensely! I would add that in Netbeans the full path tends to be the packagename/file.fxml

Answer (score 1):

My fxml file wasn't at the same folder that main (neither on the same package). The only way that I got is using:  getClass().getResource("/fxml/inicial.fxml");